# How to measure tomatoes for making sauce?

Tags: sauce, tomatoes

In the ingredient list my recipe calls for 10 lbs of tomatoes. I'm not sure if this means before or after they are cored and peeled. What is the best way to measure tomatoes for canning sauce?

Comment: This came up in another question once ... unless it calls for '10 lbs of cored & peeled tomatoes', it means measure before.  Especially if one of the steps calls for coring & peeling.  (the other option is '10 lbs of tomatoes, cored and peeled' which is more debatable, but I'd still argue for it being pre-cored weight for the reason Willem mentions)

Answer (score 3):

Unless specified, I would assume *before* cored and peeled.

And in general for any ingredient, unless explicitly specified: Raw, as bought in the store, before cleaning and/or preparation.

It makes assembling a shopping list easier, it makes buying easier, it makes writing a recipe easier, and it makes cooking a recipe easier.